# Is there an Italian-English Harry Potter dictionary?

Tags: harry-potter, translation

Many nouns in the Italian version of Harry Potter have been changed to something else.

Is there a comprehensive dictionary encompassing all changes? Including characters, spells, objects, places, everything.

There are a few of them (very few) listed in the introduction of every book, but it's only a very small list: I'm searching for something that at least makes some serious effort in trying to be complete.

Comment: lol @ the downvote

Comment: Italian fella here, same problem ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I would guess there is no complete list.**

The HP Wiki, while not usually considered canonical, has several articles as part of a [“Harry Potter in translation” series](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_in_translation_series) which may be useful to somebody reading the books in Italian. Each page has a list of terms and the word used in each of the translations.

Here are the lists they currently have:

- [List of characters](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_characters_in_translations_of_Harry_Potter): characters, including animals and non-humans
- [List of wizarding terms](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_wizarding_terms_in_translations_of_Harry_Potter): includes currency, magical objects, Quidditch terms and other terms specific to the Harry Potter universe
- [List of locations](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_locations_in_other_languages)

I don’t know if any more are planned, but the [series master post](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_in_translation_series) is probably the place to find such lists.

These articles probably don’t encompass *all* changes or translations, but they’re the most complete resource that I’ve found.

Answer (score 3):

I've just found this page:
http://www.diagonalley.it/traduttore.php :) 
Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Well, seeing as there's nothing as comprehensive as you describe in *English*, I doubt there would be anything like this in Italian. A quick search of US Amazon and the Wikipedia does not show any *Harry Potter* compilations. Originally, J.K. Rowling was going to do a *Harry Potter* encyclopedia, which she took to calling "The Scottish Book", but eventually the idea of writing a massive book morphed into the Pottermore website, which has [an Italian version](https://www.pottermore.com/it).

Personally, I would die for an accurate and comprehensive *Harry Potter* compilation!